# c++ storing a char list from a char* function

Tags: c++, arrays, string

This code delete duplicated letters from a string how could i store this returned value in a variable and make operations on it ?

```
char *removeDuplicate(char str[], int n)
{
// Used as index in the modified string
int index = 0;

// Traverse through all characters
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {

 // Check if str[i] is present before it
 int j;
 for (j=0; j<i; j++)
    if (str[i] == str[j])
       break;

 // If not present, then add it to
 // result.
 if (j == i)
    str[index++] = str[i];
}

return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Both `std::string` and `std::vector<char>` work very well in general, for `char` based string-type data.  In this particular case, `std::set<char>` may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the contents of the input array, `str`. You obviously have that variable in the calling function. You can simply use it.

Say you use:

```
char title[] = "mission impossible";
removeDuplicate(title, strlen(title));
```

You can use `title` after the call to `removeDuplicate`. It will have been updated after the call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `std::string` if its possible for your context, or allocated pointer on `char*`. I will show you example for `std::string`:

```
std::string removeDuplicate(char str[], int n)
{
    // Used as index in the modified string
    int index = 0;

    // Traverse through all characters
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {

        // Check if str[i] is present before it
        int j;
        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            if (str[i] == str[j])
                break;

        // If not present, then add it to
        // result.
        if (j == i)
            str[index++] = str[i];
    }

    return std::string(str, str + index);
}

int main()
{
    char test[] = "tttsetst";

    std::string retStr = removeDuplicate(test, strlen(test)); // value is "tse"
    return 0;
}
```

At return we init std:: string with last changed pos to remove duplicated chars `std::string(str, str + index);`

Or if you don't want to return value at all, you can mark your str passed to function with '\0' in needed index to set new end of string and it will keep its value after leaving function. Because str[] passed by pointer. Look code:

```
void removeDuplicate(char str[], int n)
{
    // Used as index in the modified string
    int index = 0;

    // Traverse through all characters
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {

        // Check if str[i] is present before it
        int j;
        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            if (str[i] == str[j])
                break;

        // If not present, then add it to
        // result.
        if (j == i)
            str[index++] = str[i];
    }

    //mark end of the string
    str[index] = '\0';
}

//...
char test[] = "tttsetst";
removeDuplicate(test, strlen(test)); // test value is "tse" after leaving function
//...
```

Also it would be cheaper, you don't need to allocate new variables to store fixed string data.